# Sagging kitchen floor, no beams only joists, how to fix? Foundation issue?

Tags: floor, foundation

I previously made a post here about a sagging floor (one corner of my kitchen floor is dipping, is lower than the rest of my floor).

The home is over 100 years old, I got the house inspected they stated nothing was obviously wrong with the foundation, but because they could not get directly underneath the kitchen, they could not be certain. I spoke with a general inspector, and not a structural engineer.

The main section of my house has 3 floors and a basement. First floor is held up by wooden beams and wooden joists. There is a closet in the basement that stops me from walking underneath the kitchen. The closet has brick/mortar walls. I managed to remove the wooden shelves left by the previous owner, and was able to find a pathway through the brick that comes up right underneath the kitchen floor boards, but however the space is not really a crawl space, as the joists are blocking me from crawling in the rest of the space.

I was curious, is it possible that the rest of the kitchen is not held up by beams, and it's just joists and floor board?

Is this a sign of foundational issues? How can I fix the slope/sag? Tear out the floors and level it out?

I've attached some pictures

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Under the range is a great spot to cut into the crawl space to take a peak. Pull it out of that spot and cut out flooring and floor sheathing to get access to the space. At least for a camera if not yourself. Under the fridge and dishwasher are additional candidate spots for gaining access. With no vents, there should be a moisture  barrier over the soil to prevent your floor joists from rotting. That rusty pipe in the foundation could be a vent, but that alone would be totally inadequate.

Comment: can you take a picture from further back of the corner of the house with the kitchen?  the close up pictures make the corner of the under kitchen look a chimney or shoot.  Maybe there was a cut out for a coal drop originally which was then built overtop.  If the picture of the single piece of dimensional lumber that is resting on the brick is the support for your kitchen corner floor then the out of level could just be a function of the levelness of the brick for that as a support.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger so that cutout, that closeup of the brick and joist. That is not the same corner as where the sag is. I was able to access that cutout/joist by clearing out my closet in the basement. But the actual cut out is closer to the entrance of the kitchen than the corner with the sag. I am not able to check where the actual sag is happening because the area with the cutout/joist , there isn't enough space for me to walk through. That joist appears to be resting on brick. The corner in picture 7 is where the sag is. The cutout is about in the entrance to the kitchen, in picture 6.